# Centering empty divs

Tags: html, css

I'm a kind of newbie on CSS and I'm trying to make a layout composed only by `DIVs`. Look at this example, it's a compact version of my layout and show what I'm having difficulty:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .all .text, .all .divs {
        text-align: center
    }
    .all .divs div {
        background-color: #000;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        margin-top: 5px
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="all">
        <div class="text">
            Hi! I'm align in the center!
        </div>

        <div class="divs">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Look that `div` with `class="text"` is center aligned but `class="divs"` is not. I'm think this happens cause divs in `class="divs"` have no text inside. Is it right?

My question is how can I center the divs inside `class="divs"` on screen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"text-align: center" property is used for centering text, images etc. INSIDE a div or other block element.
If you need to center a div itself, then you need to use "margin: 0 auto". But, the width of the div must be defined and it is also must be smaller, than a user screen width (not 100%).

Examples:

```
.all .text, .all .divs {
  width: 500px; margin: 0 auto;
}

.all .text, .all .divs {
  width: 90%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `text-align` for centering divs, but `margin: 0 auto;`

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `auto`. The browser will set the margins for you. In your case it's as simple as using the following

```
.all .divs div {
    /*other stuff*/
    margin: 5px auto 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
.all, .divs, .divs div{
margin:0px auto;}
```

Like so, http://jsfiddle.net/EzC44/